# Google Docs API: Image insertion fails with rate limit error

Tags: image, google-docs-api, rate-limiting

I use the Java Google Drive API to upload a document consisting of text with about 100 images. I produce a request like this:

```
List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
for (...) {
   requests.add(new Request().setInsertText(...));
   requests.add(new Request().setInsertInlineImage(...));
}
BatchUpdateDocumentRequest body = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest().setRequests(requests);
BatchUpdateDocumentResponse response = service.documents().batchUpdate(id, body).execute();
```

This has worked well for quite a while. However, since today, the tool fails with

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 429 Too Many Requests
{
  "code" : 429,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
    "reason" : "rateLimitExceeded"
  } ],
  "message" : "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
  "status" : "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
}
```

The quota page shows that I am well within the quota for write requests. And indeed, if I don't include images, I can write additional documents. But as soon as I add a single image, the request fails.

Is there a hidden quota somewhere? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The requests you have been making - have you made many image upload requests using this GCP project? [`429 is because of short-term quotas so exponential backoff may help](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/handle-errors#resolve_a_429_error_too_many_requests)

Comment: I am not sure what counts as "many requests". The document that I build has about 100 images. So I make one BatchUpdateRequest containing about 200 individual requests for images and text. Does that count as 1 or as 200? The page for https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/docs.googleapis.com/quotas shows 1 write operation for each run, so I assumed the former.

Comment: There is no official documentation that explicitly says how many requests are "too many" - but a batch request can only have a maximum of 100 requests in it. Try shortening the length of the batchRequest to be no more than 100.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the document that you are using at that moment, try to make a new document, and run the batch update again with the new document id. this would solve the image insertion fail.